# No padding between columns on ion-col?

Tags: css, ionic3

[image]   [![ioncol][2]][2]I am having a problem with ion-col. I want it if type == 'A' to be col-12 if any other type col-6. Plus i dont want so much padding between ion-cards. Item 4 is 200 px height and item 3 is 100 px height. I dont want to have any blank space on the page or padding. Any help?

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col [class.col-6]="item.type!='A'"
        [class.col.12]="item.type==='A'" *ngFor="let item of items">
            <ion-card *ngIf="item.type==='A'" style="border-radius: 10px 5px;">
                Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1, Item 1,
            </ion-card>
            <ion-card *ngIf="item.type==='B'" style="border-radius: 10px 5px;">
                Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2, Item 2,
            </ion-card>
            <ion-card *ngIf="item.type==='C'" style="border-radius: 10px 5px;height:100px">
                Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3, Item 3,
            </ion-card>
            <ion-card *ngIf="item.type==='D'" style="border-radius: 10px 5px;height:200px">
                Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4, Item 4,
            </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) @Simonloa u just need to be fixed card height. and add css in this card time will be show dot (...) or read more if content increase.

2) just add  and also add class="ion-no-padding" in ion-col

You must read this.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities

Comment: i did add no-padding but the padding continues. I used no-padding in many cases and it works but not here. i just need to get rid of the whitespace between ion-cards

Comment: R u using Ionic3?

Comment: ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.8.0 (C:\Users\Simos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.5, (and 14 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Simos\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.13.0 
   npm               : 6.4.1

Comment: I find out about your problem. you just need to add [col-12] for type A and [col-6] for other. You follow the Ionic 3 doc [https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/responsive-grid/] because it's project is developed into ionic 3 and upgrade into ionic 4. so use this link i'll be help u.

Comment: [col-12]="item.type==='A'"
[col-6]="item.type!=='A'"

Comment: The link you send me replies a 404.  THE CLI IS 4.8 I AM USING IONIC V3

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/responsive-grid/ use this. there is a "]" on end in the link. that's creating issue.

Comment: The [class.col-6]="item.type!='V'" [class.col.12]="item.type==='V'" works for me. The problem is that i dont want to any empty space between ion-cards. I change the ion-card with ion-item but there is a lot of whitespace inside the ion-item

Comment: like Pinterest does with images, i want no empty space between ion-cards regardless of the height of each type. i have updated the attached photo

Comment: kindly set ion-card heigh.

Comment: i did that i want to be different heights according to type. E.g. type.B 100px height, type C 200px height?